# Convert OpenCV part of image to NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa, opencv

I'm trying to read an image using OpenCV, get a part of it and show it in an NSImageView object.
Here is how I'm doing.

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("/Users/maddev/Documents/R8.jpg");
cv::Mat reduced = im(cv::Rect(10, 10, 400, 400));
std::vector<unsigned char> data ;
unsigned char *ptr = reduced.data;
unsigned long size = reduced.total() * reduced.elemSize();
data.assign(ptr, ptr + size);
int cols = reduced.cols;
int rows = reduced.rows;

// to NSImage
unsigned char *pimage = &data[0];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep=[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                       initWithBitmapDataPlanes:&pimage
                       pixelsWide:cols
                       pixelsHigh:rows
                       bitsPerSample:8
                       samplesPerPixel:3
                       hasAlpha:NO
                       isPlanar:NO
                       colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                       bytesPerRow:cols*3
                       bitsPerPixel:24
                       ];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[rep CGImage] size:NSMakeSize(cols,rows)];
imageView.image = image;
```

which doesn't work, getting some garbage displayed. 
But if I use same approach on `im` object then everything works as expected.
Why `reduced` cannot be displayed properly? Do I need to check anything else when creating `NSBitmapImageRep` object?

Thx

P.S. Please ignore the vector stuff, this problem is part of a bigger solution and this is the only way I can bring the image bytes into main application from a cv:Mat picture.

Comment: Don’t know know why this was downvoted. Only thing I can figure is down voters didn’t really understand what you are trying to do — I am about to do the same thing. Illegitimi non carborundum.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll answer to myself. 
The solution was actually pretty easy, when a new `cv::Mat` is created only the image header is copied, but it still point to the original image data, this leads to a wrong picture display.

All I had to is to use `copyTo` method when creating the cropped version to actually copy needed data form big picture to the small one and then all worked as needed.

something like this

```
cv::Mat reduced;
orig(roi).copyTo(reduced);
```